# Codeigniter - how to passing foreach value to inside of array

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps, foreach, codeigniter-3

I use CodeIgniter 3 and libraries of http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/ .
When I take the data from the database and put it into the polygon points, I encountered some error .

> Severity: Warning Message: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given Filename: libraries/Googlemaps.php 
>   Line Number: 2179

my controller function :

```
public function testing()
    {
    $config['center'] = '-8.1768084, 113.6559507';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $kecamatan = $this->Peta_model->get_kecamatan();
    foreach ($kecamatan as $k) {
        $kcmt = $k->name;
        $coor = $this->Peta_model->get_coor_by_kcmt($kcmt);
        if ($coor) {
            $polygon = array(
              'points' => array() ,
              'strokeColor' => '#000099' ,
              'fillColor' => '#000099' ,
            );
            foreach ($coor as $c) {
                $polygon ['points'][] = array("'".$c->latitude.",".$c->longitude."'");
            }
            $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon);
        }
    }


    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $user_level = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->row();
    $data = array(
        'user'       => $user ,
        'user_level' => $user_level ,
        'title'      => 'Peta' , 
        'content'    => 'peta/v_peta' ,
        'map'        => $this->googlemaps->create_map(), 
    );

    $this->load->view('dashboard/layout', $data);
}
```

normaly add polygon is :

```
$polygon = array(
  'points' => array('37.425, -122.1321',
         '37.4422, -122.1622',
         '37.4412, -122.1322',
         '37.425, -122.1021') ,
  'strokeColor' => '#000099' ,
  'fillColor' => '#000099' ,
);
$this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon);
```

how do I fix it ?

Comment: what is the line #2179?

Comment: line #2179 from library. http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !. only cahange

```
$polygon ['points'][] = array("'".$c->latitude.",".$c->longitude."'");
```

to

```
$polygon ['points'][] = $c->latitude.','.$c->longitude;
```

thank you @Muhammad Suhaib

Answer (score 0):

You are storing an array in `$polygon ['points'][]`.

i think you should store a string. like..

```
$polygon ['points'][] = "'".$c->latitude.",".$c->longitude."'";
```

Comment: i will tray, tanks for your answer .